# not smoothly connecting between two objecs using boolean union

Tags: bevel, boolean-modifier

[image]

Hi, i want to make a smooth boolean between the X form and the "prongs" sticking out of it. I tried union and a clean up, i also tried offset cut but both did not make it smooth, bevel does not do antything...

Comment: https://we.tl/t-CThSTZMyuU this is the object with a boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should better redo it: First in *Edit* mode select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide* to simplify the topology (tweak the parameter in the *Operator Box*, you can even simplify more), select 8 faces:

[image]

Inset <kbd>i</kbd> then right click > *LoopTools > Circle* (you need to enable the *LoopTools* addon):

[image]

Extrude up, fill the top faces with <kbd>F</kbd>:

[image]

Bevel the top and bevel the bottom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>):

[image]

Give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]